# Как вывести комментарии в ленте постов по каждым постом?

Tags: wordpress

нужно создать на сайте страницу микроблога и вывести под постами комментарии в ленте постов ,как тут
https://p2demo.wordpress.com/
тоесть в ленте постов пост как под ним сделать возможеость оставить кометарий прямо в ленте не переходя на страницу поста как в вконтате
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для одиночных страниц/постов для вывода комментариев достаточно:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

Вордпресс сам все выведет и даже стилизовано будет стандартно. [По поводу функции можно почитать здесь.](https://wp-kama.ru/function/comments_template)

!НО вот для вашего случая(много постов), этого недостаточно из-за проверок в шаблоне и функции вывода комментариев.

**Шаблон: wp-content\themes\twentytwenty\template-parts\content.php**

```
if ( ( is_single() || is_page() ) && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) && ! post_password_required() )
```

**Функция: wp-includes\comment-template.php**

```
if ( ! ( is_single() || is_page() || $withcomments ) || empty( $post ) )
```

Поэтому, топорное решение(возможно все же для этих целей есть плагины, или более разумные решения) - исключить страницу блога из запретов.

**Для функции**: скопировать функцию, добавить в function.php, переименовать, добавить разрешение ( `is_home()` )

```
if ( ! ( is_single() || is_page()|| is_home() || $withcomments ) || empty( $post ) )
```

**Для шаблона**:

```
<?php
    if ( ( is_single() || is_page() || is_home() ) && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) && ! post_password_required() ) {
        ?>

        <div class="comments-wrapper section-inner">

            <?php comments_template_new(); ?>

        </div><!-- .comments-wrapper -->

        <?php
    }
?>
```

Результат:
[image: Скрин результата]

**Важно:** Проверялось на основе стандартной темы twentytwenty

**Важно!:** Существенно увеличивается количество запросов к базе данных(даже для 3х комментариев + 10 запросов)

Comment: если я правильно понял ,все что выше то добавил в function.php
[ссылка](http://prntscr.com/ughxcd)   [ссылка](https://prnt.sc/ughyco)

Comment: в файле comments.php скопировал его и поменял вот это 
<?php comment_form( array('action' => '/wp-comments-post-mikro.php',
          'label_submit' => esc_attr__('Post Comment', 'extra' ),
          'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . esc_html_x( 'COMMENT', 'noun', 'extra') . '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>', 
          'title_reply' => '<span>' . esc_attr__('Leave a reply', 'extra' ) . '</span>',
          'title_reply_to' => esc_attr__('Leave a Reply to %s', 'extra' ) ) ); ?>

Comment: и добавил редирект в файле wp-comments-post-mikro.php который копия wp-comments-post.php $location = "/mikroblog/" . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID;
wp_safe_redirect( $location );

Comment: а как добавить возможность добавления картинки или ссылки в комментарий или плагина ark-wysiwyg-comment-editor

Comment: а это уже другой вопрос, на текущий по отображению я ответила? - кажется да. А вот расширение комментариев/фильтры - это уже другой вопрос. Как минимум - попробуйте плагины поискать, например, такой DCO Comment Attachment . Задача намного шире, чем пару строчек в шаблонах поправить -  тут я не помощник.

Comment: пробовал так но он работает id ,поэтому на странице 1 поле только
`function mayak_editor_comments(){
$settings = array(
  'media_buttons'=>0,
  'textarea_name'=>'comment',
  'quicktags'=>0,
  'teeny'=>0,
  'tinymce'=> 1,
  'textarea_rows'=>10,
);
$aut = wp_editor('', 'comment', $settings);
return $aut;
}
<?php mayak_editor_comments(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

в header.php

добавить код инициализации

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://userapi.com/js/api/openapi.js?34"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
VK.init({apiId: API_ID, onlyWidgets: true});
</script>
```

в functions.php добавить

```
add_filter('the_content', 'add_vk_widget', 10, 2);

function add_vk_widget($content) {
    
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    
    $content .= '<div id="vk_comments_'.$post_id.'"></div>';
    
    $content .= '<script type="text/javascript">';
    
    $content .= 'VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: 20, width: "496", attach: "*"}, page_id : "'.$post_id.'");';
    
    $content .= '</script>';
    
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: комvентарии вк не нужны нужны вордпресовские но вид ленты как в VK,то есть пос комментарий ,в этом плане

Comment: виджет тогда замените на вызов comments_template(); подробнее тут https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_template/

Comment: а плагин не подскажите ,а то пробовал стандартные комментарии от поста ,но вложенные не работаю правильно ,не на страницы поста

/* if ( ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) && 'on' == et_get_option( 'extra_show_postcomments', 'on' ) ) {comments_template( '', true );
}*/
в wp-comments-post.php редиректит на пост wp_safe_redirect( $location );

Comment: вот тут этот вариант делал http://egocreo.webalgoritm.tmweb.ru/%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3/

Comment: может как-то переопределить это  фильтр для этой страницы ,но не знаю за что зацепится так как url будет менятся если можно как то проверит типа is_page_post_coment_list():
$location = apply_filters( 'comment_post_redirect', $location, $comment );

wp_safe_redirect( $location );

Comment: попробуйте в шаблоне внутри цикла while ( have_posts() ) : .... endwhile; на страницах категории (archive.php, category.php) вставить  <?php if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) { comments_template(); }?>